# What does eating and drinking do?

Tags: watch-dogs-2

I recently started playing Watch_Dogs 2 and have been enjoying the game a lot. I have been wondering though, during my exploration of San Francisco I have noticed food and drink icons while I have been driving around hacking the planet. I went on in to check out what was there and I was able to drink beer or coffee at no cost (great deal by the way) but doing so doesn't seem to have any noticeable difference or change. Is it just some sort of ascetic thing that you can eat or drink or does it actually have some sort of affect on gameplay or your character?

Comment: Thanks, Gaming, for once again making the HNQ list more confusing.

Comment: Just doing my part @EngineerToast :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Drinking and eating in Watch Dogs 2 doesn't bring anything to the game. It won't affect your character, nor it will affect the gameplay of the game. So you can just keep eating and drinking as much as you want, or just totally ignore it.

There was some purpose for it in the first game. Drinking soft drinks for instance would heal you and regenerate your focus meter. But it was not kept for the second game.

Comment: I believe in the first game there were also the drinking games which were a type of challenge and were actually difficult later on.

Comment: Oh yeah I do believe I remember that @TimmyJim yeah I remember that minigame actually got pretty tricky.

Answer (score 2):

From [this thread](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/191233-watch-dogs-2/74572736), it looks like they're just aesthetic and don't really have an impact on you.

> Yeah, I tested it out at a bar and for 5 minutes I just kept drinking beer, must of drank at least 30... nothing happened. Its cool they threw it in, but its just weird that it has NO purpose considering how many locations there are, and they show up on your map like they mean something.

It's worth noting that in [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/watch_dogs/comments/5hmcdv/why_the_eating_or_drinking_beer_gives_nothing/), its indicated that eating and drinking *used* to play a role in the original Watch_Dogs, but don't anymore.

> Well the purpose of there being drinks in the first game like energy drinks, coffee, etc. was to fill aiden's focus meter. Marcus doesn't have that any more.

Comment: That's kind of disappointing I was hoping maybe getting hyped up on coffee or getting really drunk on beer. Not enough games have heavy drinking like GTA4 did.

Comment: @Ramirez you could always just do that in real life while *playing* the game! ;)